# What is negative inversion for "She made no sound as she crept upstairs"?

Tags: inversion, negative-inversion

What is the negative inversion for this sentence?

> She made no sound as she crept upstairs

My Answer:

> No sound did she made as she crept upstairs

Is this correct? If not, how could it be improved?

Answer (score 3):

> No sound did she made as she crept upstairs

No, it's not quite correct.  It should be "No sound did she make..." - not "made".

When you invert, you have to add do-support.  So your original sentence

> She made no sound as she crept upstairs

becomes (prior to inversion)

> She did make no sound as she crept upstairs

(The verb following the auxiliary "do"/"did" is untensed - "make", a bare infinitive - not "made".)

When inverted, that makes:

> No sound did she make as she crept upstairs